# How was it possible for people to remain enslaved until 1869?

Tags: slavery, american-civil-war

In [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henrietta_Wood), we read that Wood's enslaver marched his slaves to Texas after the Civil War where she remained enslaved to him until 1869. This is the first I have heard of this. How is this possible? Texas of course was part of the USA after the war. How common was this and what was the legal status of the abducted people? What did the local government try to do about it and what the the federal government try to do?

The history of slavery in Texas article in Wikipedia mentions nothing about post-war enslavement.

Comment: This was illegal, not legal slavery; and simply a matter of Brandon evading, for nearly 4 years, officers equipped to free his slaves.

Comment: The article Wikipedia cites says she was freed in 1866 but continued to work for her enslaver. https://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/henrietta-wood-sued-reparations-won-180972845/

Comment: People remain enslaved in the United States to this day. There aren't many of them, and they are usually illegal immigrants that can't speak English. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contemporary_slavery_in_the_United_States#:~:text=The%20practices%20of%20slavery%20and,those%20being%20women%20and%20children.